# SWIFT : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain json Parse error

Tags: ios, json, swift

hello I have a data like this coming from server

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "msg": [{
        "Trip": {
            "trip_id": "47",
            "user_id": "69",
            "trip_title": "xxx",
            "trip_summary": "Xxxxc",
            "departure_country_id": "233702",
            "arrival_country_id": "233702",
            "departure_date": "2016-05-26 10:29:31",
            "destination_date": "2019-04-26 10:29:31",
            "item_name": "",
            "product_image_path": "app\/webroot\/uploads\/69\/Trip\/571fa5bd2b056test.png",
            "price": "0",
            "fee": "88",
            "trip_post_date": "2016-04-26 05:30:37",
            "active": false
        },
        "User": {
            "user_id": "69",
            "first_name": "jenje",
            "last_name": "nenej",
            "profile_image": "app\/webroot\/uploads\/69\/Profile\/571e69a16592auSSLa.png",
            "country": "Pakistan",
            "phone_no": "00000000"
        },
        "departure_country": {
            "id": "233702",
            "short_country_name": "AD",
            "country_name": "Andorra",
            "state_name": "Andorra la Vella",
            "city_name": "Andorra la Vella"
        },
        "arrival_country": {
            "id": "233702",
            "short_country_name": "AD",
            "country_name": "Andorra",
            "state_name": "Andorra la Vella",
            "city_name": "Andorra la Vella"
        }
    }, {
        "Trip": {
            "trip_id": "46",
            "user_id": "69",
            "trip_title": "vhh",
            "trip_summary": "Bhhh",
            "departure_country_id": "15095",
            "arrival_country_id": "688987",
            "departure_date": "2019-04-26 07:32:36",
            "destination_date": "2019-04-26 07:32:36",
            "item_name": "",
            "product_image_path": "app\/webroot\/uploads\/69\/Trip\/571f7c64df6c7test.png",
            "price": "0",
            "fee": "25",
            "trip_post_date": "2016-04-26 02:34:12",
            "active": false
        },
        "User": {
            "user_id": "69",
            "first_name": "jenje",
            "last_name": "nenej",
            "profile_image": "app\/webroot\/uploads\/69\/Profile\/571e69a16592auSSLa.png",
            "country": "Pakistan",
            "phone_no": "00000000"
        },
        "departure_country": {
            "id": "15095",
            "short_country_name": "AE",
            "country_name": "United Arab Emirates",
            "state_name": "Abu Dhabi",
            "city_name": "Abu Dhabi"
        },
        "arrival_country": {
            "id": "688987",
            "short_country_name": "AD",
            "country_name": "Andorra",
            "state_name": "Encamp",
            "city_name": "Encamp"
        }
    }]
}
```

I am using this code

```
let json: NSDictionary?
                do {
                    json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary


                } catch let dataError {
                    // Did the JSONObjectWithData constructor return an error? If so, log the error to the console
                    print(dataError)
}
```

But it is giving me json parse error. Let me know if you need the whole code. Please help.

**Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}**

Comment: can you please tell domain code error?

Comment: The JSON is valid.

Comment: "No value" means the JSON string / `data` is empty.

Comment: @vadian Thanks I figure it out. data was coming empty